# Objective-C Problems While Transitioning Between Views

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, transition, nsexception

I'm having issues transitioning between views and need some help.  This is somewhat conviluted so bear with me please.

I have a UINavigationController called `JobsNavController`.  The first view in JobsNavController holds a UITableViewController called `JobsTableViewController` [with a linked nib called `JobTableView.xib`].  I want to add an `Add` UIButton inside the UINavController to 'create a new job'.  When clicked, it should flip from `JobTableView.xib` to my `JobCreateViewController` nib called `JobCreateView.xib`.  Since the 'add' button is located within the UINavController I put the IBAction code inside `JobsNavController.h and .m`.

Here is the `JobsNavController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class JobCreateViewController, JobsTableViewController;

@interface JobsNavController : UINavigationController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnJobCreate;
    IBOutlet JobCreateViewController *jobCreateViewController;
        IBOutlet JobsTableViewController *jobsTableViewController;
}
-(IBAction)tellDelegateToFlip:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *btnJobCreate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet JobCreateViewController *jobCreateViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet JobsTableViewController *jobsTableViewController;

@end
```

And here is my `JobsNavController.m`

```
#import "JobsNavController.h", "Time_Blogger1AppDelegate.h", "JobsTableViewController.h"
@implementation JobsNavController
@synthesize btnJobCreate, jobCreateViewController, jobsTableViewController;
.....
-(void)tellDelegateToFlip {
    JobCreateViewController *jobAddView = [jobCreateViewController initWithNibName:@"JobCreateView" bundle:nil];

    [self setJobCreateViewController:jobAddView];
    [jobAddView release];

    UIViewController *transitionTo = jobCreateViewController;

    //create view animation block
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [jobsTableViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview:transitionTo.view atIndex:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [transitionTo release];
}
```

I'm not getting any build/compile errors but the simulator throws an exception when I click the button stating:

```
2012-01-22 19:19:22.895 Time-Blogger1[4209:f803] 
-[JobsNavController tellDelegateToFlip:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c85e80 2012-01-22 19:19:22.897 Time-Blogger1[4209:f803] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[JobsNavController tellDelegateToFlip:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c85e80'
```

Comment: If you add the code where you call `tellDelegateToFlip` I think I can show you exactly where/why it crashes.

Comment: @Rickay that is all my code for `tellDelegateToFlip`

Comment: I meant the code where you *call* the method, not implement it.

Comment: I showed the call to the method in my JobsNavController.h code section above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `tellDelegateToFlip` make sure you do it with no parameters- this is what is causing the crash. If you notice in the crash report, it says the unrecognized selector `tellDelegateToFlip:` is being sent to your instance. Notice the colon coming after the method name. This means that wherever you called the method, you sent an object with it. If you are using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` make sure you *don't* use a colon.

Edit:

Instead of:

```
UIViewController* transitionTo = jobCreateViewController;
```

why don't you just use:

```
JobCreateViewController* transitionTo = jobCreateViewController;
```

Or you could cast it, assuming that `JobCreateViewController` inherits from UIViewController.

Comment: that solved my problem however I am now getting a warning on line `UIViewController *transitionTo = ...`.  Stating: "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UIViewController *' with an expression of types 'JobCreateViewController *'"

Comment: I'm unclear as to why you are declaring it with the type UIViewController. Why not just declare it as a `JobCreateViewController*`?

Comment: can you provide the syntax line replacement I would use in order to do it your way?

Comment: When I implement your suggestion I get the following error on this line: `[self.view insertSubview:transitionTo.view atIndex:0];`, `Property 'view' cannot be found in forward class object 'JobCreateViewController *'`

Comment: Of what class is `JobCreateViewController` a subclass?

Comment: Are you importing the JobCreateViewController.h file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6951/discussion-between-sadmicrowave-and-rickay)

Comment: can we chat about this some more? click the link in the comment above please

Answer (score 1):

wrong implementation of the method:

```
-(IBAction)tellDelegateToFlip:(id)sender;
```

should be:

```
-(IBAction)tellDelegateToFlip:(id)sender {
...
}
```

in your JobsNavController.m